# XPath & PHP: Matching text after a <br>

Tags: php, text, xpath, match

I'm trying to sort through a large list of video links. I'm wanting to sort them by `2014, 2013, 2012`, and so on, so as an example, I'm after an `XPath` query to get the '`2014`', and retrieve all the movies that match 2014.

*My effort:* Tried matching text and checking for text after `<br>`, but that retrieves every single thing after every `<br>` in the document!

Maybe something with a text match as well? I.e. `after <br> and text() = '2014 - '`?

```
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>
<br>
2014 -
<a id="3447" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">The MovieName1</a>
<br>
2014 -
<a id="3595" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">MovieName2</a>
<br>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying

```
//a[preceding-sibling::node()[1][contains(self::text(), '2014')]]
```

This will actually select the `a` elements for 2014, which I think is what you're actually after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `xpath` expression:

```
//a[contains(preceding-sibling::text()[1], "2014")]
```

This basically means: give me all of the `a` tags that has a text before it, containing `2014`.

---

Demo:

Imagine you have the following `index.html` file:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <br/>
                    2014 -
                    <a id="3447" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">The MovieName1</a>
                    <br/>
                    2014 -
                    <a id="3595" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">MovieName2</a>
                    <br/>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, here is the output of [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) xpath test:

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//a[contains(preceding-sibling::text()[1], "2014")]'
<a id="3447" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">The MovieName1</a>
<a id="3595" class="tippable" href="www.examplemovie.com" style="color:#fff">MovieName2</a>
```

Comment: This would have false positives if OP's HTML contained something like: `<br/>2014 - <a href="www.examplemovie.com">The movie</a><br /><a href="home.html">Home </a><a href="about.html">About</a>`